# Android alertlistener with optional parameters

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Just wondering whether the following is possible to do within Android / Java.
In one of my activities I have many Alert Dialogs launching new intents at the press of button. Rather than doing a lot of repeating I would like to try to build something like the following:

```
Alert(this, "Do you like A?", "yes", "no, I like B", classA.class, classB.class)

public void Alert(Context context, String question, String answerPositive, String answerNegative, Class newIntentA, Class newIntentB) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setMessage(question).setPositiveButton(answerPositive, AlertListener(context, newIntentA, newIntentB)).setNegativeButton(answerNegative, AlertListener(context, newIntentA, newIntentB)).show();
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener AlertListener(Context context, Class newIntentA, Class newIntentB) = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                Intent a = new Intent(context, newIntentA);
                startActivity(a);                    
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                Intent b = new Intent(context, newIntentB);
                startActivity(b); 
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Is this even possible? Right now I am messing up when calling `AlertListener(context, newIntentA, newIntentB)`. Also `DialogInterface.OnClickListener AlertListener(Context context, Class newIntentA, Class newIntentB) = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` does not seem correct to me. Is it possible approaching my issue like this. Maybe someone has an (easier) alternative?

EDIT1: alternative code:

```
public void Alert(final Context context, String question, String answerPositive, String answerNegative, final Class newIntentA, final Class newIntentB) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setMessage(question).setPositiveButton(answerPositive, AlertListener).setNegativeButton(answerNegative, AlertListener).show();

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener AlertListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    Intent a = new Intent(context, newIntentA);
                    startActivity(a);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    Intent b = new Intent(context, newIntentB);
                    startActivity(b);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The issue is now that I get a 'cannot resolve symbol AlertListener'.

Comment: I am messing up when calling `AlertListener(context, newIntentA, newIntentB)` ? Whats wrong? Stacktrace?

Comment: Due to the added '(Context context, Class newIntentA, Class newIntentB)' after AlertListener I get the following errors: for '= new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()' I get the error Unexpected Token. For @override I get 'annotations not allowed here'. And my 'onClick' is not used and I therefore get the 'Cannot resolve symbol' for 'dialog', 'context' and 'newIntentA+B'

Comment: I added an alternative code. Less issues, but still something fundametally wrong with this code (I believe that the onclicklistener cannot be in the Alert function as I did within the first example)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
Alert(this, "do you want A?", "yes", "no I want B", A.class, B.class);
//or
Alert(this, "do you want A?", "yes", "no I want nothing", A.class, null);

public void Alert(final Context context, String question, String answerPositive, String answerNegative, final Class newIntentA, final Class newIntentB) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener AlertListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    if (newIntentA != null) {
                        Intent a = new Intent(context, newIntentA);
                        startActivity(a);
                    }
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    if (newIntentB != null) {
                        Intent b = new Intent(context, newIntentB);
                        startActivity(b);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setMessage(question).setPositiveButton(answerPositive, AlertListener).setNegativeButton(answerNegative, AlertListener).show();
}
```